# Discontinuous scroll - detect if the user stopped scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll, mousewheel

I am trying to detect if a user scrolls up or down. But rather than knowing, the intensity of the scroll on the trackpad I want to know how many times he used the track pad to scroll.

The idea is to replicate something similar to [this](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll), except that when the user scrolls down several times it keeps moving to the next slide (as if the user were using the keyboard).

So far, I have been using this code:

```
var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
```

But this only detects if the user is scrolling or not.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: i'm afraid that is up to the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsfiddle that shows how to do it - http://jsfiddle.net/y6Ev5/

This is what is happening here -

```
1. Detect scroll start 
2. Stop event from propagating.
3. Scroll programmatically to the next page. While scrolling,cancel all scroll events.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout and clearTimeout to force only a single movement for one mouse wheel slide. Here's an example, just change the SLIDE_TIMEOUT variable to get different results. http://jsfiddle.net/s6hU8/1/

JAVASCRIPT

```
var SLIDE_TIMEOUT = 100;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
var slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
var evtSlide = null;
var upOrDown = 0;
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", handleWheel, false);
window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", handleWheel, false);

function handleWheel(e) {
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    upOrDown = delta;
    if(evtSlide)
        window.clearTimeout(evtSlide);
    evtSlide = window.setTimeout(handleSlide, SLIDE_TIMEOUT);
}

function handleSlide() {
    var offset = upOrDown, newIndex = slideIndex;
    newIndex = (newIndex + offset + slides.length) % slides.length;
    console.log(newIndex);
    slides[slideIndex].style.zIndex = 1;
    slides[newIndex].style.zIndex = 2;
    slideIndex = newIndex;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slide"><h1>9</h1></div>
<div class="slide"><h1>8</h1></div>
<div class="slide"><h1>7</h1></div>
<div class="slide"><h1>6</h1></div>
<div class="slide"><h1>5</h1></div>
<div class="slide"><h1>4</h1></div>
<div class="slide"><h1>3</h1></div>
<div class="slide"><h1>2</h1></div>
<div class="slide"><h1>1</h1></div>
```

CSS

```
.slide {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    padding:0;margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:200%;
    bac
```

kground-color:white;
}